# javascript input validation

Tags: javascript, python, validation

i am using javascript validation for my input box from [javascript-coder](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml/comment-page-2#comments) but i have 2 problems here.

First: The validator in the script uses name to validate the object, is it possible to change to id in the gen_validatorv4.js and how?

Second: my page reloads itself despite of alert produces by the textbox. it's suppose to stay on the page and allow user to correct error.

below is my script placement

```
    function submitform(){
    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("myform");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("amountperIteration","numeric","Name a price greater than $25");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("amountperIteration","gt=25","Name a price greater than $25");
    
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

my html code is simplify to something like that: (my back end is using python)

```
 <form action="{{ request.path }}" name="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return false">
 <input type="text" name="amountperIteration">
 <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitform">
 </form>
```

Any advice?

Comment: You should accept some of the questions you've asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your second question:

If validation fails, you want to `return false` from the submit handler:

```
function submitForm() {
    var result = validate(this);

    if ( result === false ) { return false; }
}
```

That way the form submission process will be canceled.

Comment: 'this' in validate() method validate base on what?

Comment: @pivotal If the above function is used as a submit handler, then the `this` value references the FORM element that is being submitted. But this depends on how you set the submit handler - if you do it programatically, like so: `form.onsubmit = submitForm;`, then it should work. If you do it via the onsubmit attribute in the HTML code, then I'm not so sure - in that case teh `this` value may reference the global object instead.