# Script won't stop after failing validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I am using javascript validation for my input box from [javascript-coder](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml) and it works fine on my non-ajax pages but when I use ajax to POST inputs the script runs through without stopping even if validation fails. I tried an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958773/javascript-input-validation) but when I tried the suggestion the validation didn't work at all. In my ajax script I can get everything to work with jquery validation by simply putting this in before posting data:

```
var frm = $(this).closest('form');        
        if($(frm).valid()){
```

But I really want to stick with this validation library so I am hoping someone in the community more familiar javascript and maybe even this validation library can help me find an equivalent because I haven't been able to find anything in all the documentation that allows you to test if validation failed or not before moving my ajax script forward.

My form:

```
<form method="post" name="send_message_frm" id="send_message_frm">
        <div style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
        <fieldset>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <div style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
          <label>Product Group Name:</label>
          <input name="desc" class="text-input medium3-input required" type="text" id="desc" value="">
          <div style="color:red;" id='send_message_frm_desc_errorloc' ></div>
          <div style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
        </fieldset>
        <input name="user" class="text-input medium3-input" type="hidden" id="user" value="<?php echo $myid ; ?>">
        <div style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
         <input type="submit" id="send-message" name="submit" value="Send" class='button'  />
        <div style="margin-top:20px;"></div>
      </form>  
<script  type="text/javascript">


    var frmvalidator = new Validator("send_message_frm");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
    frmvalidator.addValidation("desc","alnum","Only numbers and letters are allowed");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("desc","req","Please enter a description");


</script>
```

My Ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Validate form....what can I put here to test if validation is completed properly????

    //onclick handler send message btn
    $("#send-message").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('form').submit(function(){
            return false;
        });
        var frm = $(this).closest('form');        

            $("#ajax-loading").show();
            var data = $(frm).serialize();
            $(frm).find('textarea,select,input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');            
            $.post( 
                    "productgroup_add.php", 
                    data, 
                    function(data){ 
                        $("#ajax-loading").hide();
                        $(frm).find('textarea,select,input').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $("#send_message_frm").prepend(data);
                    } 
           );
        }
    );
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the validation script, I discovered (as suspected) that it attaches the validation method to the form's OnSubmit event handler, which sounds about right...

```
this.formobj.onsubmit = form_submit_handler;
```

But... it also attaches itself to the form object:

```
this.formobj.validatorobj = this;
```

which has a method that you can call to validate your form:

```
if (!this.runAddnlValidations())
```

To run the validations, it looks like you can just do something like:

```
if(!document.forms[0].validatorobj.runAddnlValidations()) return;
```

Comment: okay, I jumped the gun. Apparently I have no clue what I'm doing. So I tried to put if(!form_submit_handler()) return; before my ajax function but all that did was cause the function to fail. I've tried several variations to try and use if(!form_submit_handler()) to give me a boolean answer on whether or not the validations have succeeded or not but I'm getting super lost. I'm okay with PHP but clueless on javascript so can you expand on your meaning of running the event handler myself? Where am I placing what? Should I be placing something after my validation to see if it passed?

Comment: @DevNewb - it's difficult to know what went wrong, but I updated my answer anyway with a different approach.  Hope it works out.

Comment: I'm really trying here but I'm not quite getting your advice. So my validations run ok. Then I have my ajax script and whether the validations have failed or not the ajax script completes itself, even if validations failed and thats the problem. So I can see the error message pop up from the validation failing but information still gets submitted to the database. I need something that says: if(validations havent failed){};  Then the ajax will only run if validations passed. Are you saying I can do: if(!document.forms[0].validatorobj.runAddnlValidations()){AJAX goes here}???